# Adding iOS Dictation (microphone) Button to Keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am currently making my UISearchBar first responder and the following keyboard is produced (sorry, my rep isn't high enough to post images):

http://i57.tinypic.com/2jexyyu.png

I plan on using a third-party API to implement speech-to-text. In order to make the user experience as friendly and familiar as possible, I'd like to add the microphone/diction button on the keyboard just to the left of the space bar, and use some sort of delegate methods to watch for the pressing of the button to make the API calls.

Here's the keyboard I want:
http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/iOS-7-Keyboard-Shortcuts-002.png

How would I go about doing this, if it is even possible?

Comment: Currently, I think it can't be done. However, iOS 8 is expected to provide support for 3rd-party keyboards.

Comment: Turn on 'Siri' in settings app